# ¿En cuestion de rendimiento es mas factible usar null o vacio?

Tags: string

Lo que quiero saber especificamente es cual deberia usar a la hora de hacer una insercion en una tabla de una base de datos, estamos hablando de tablas que pueden alojar mas de 5000 registros. Tengo un campo que en la mayoria de los casos se almacena como una cadena vacia. En mi ignorancia diria que pesa mas una cadena vacia que un `null`. Pero no estoy seguro, por eso quiero respuestas idoneas para saber si deba pasar de `null` a vacio antes de hacer la insercion.

Comment: La diferencia de tamaño sería despreciable (especialmente solo para 5000 registros). Quizás sería más interesante enfocarse en velocidad/rendimiento y facilidad de uso, donde puede haber más diferencias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema en realidad es del diseño de la tabla, porque necesitas tener un campo que casi siempre es vacío en la misma tabla con todos los otros valores??

Puede que simplemente sea mejor crear una tabla relacionada y que solo se inserte un valor en esa cuando se tenga, eso te ahorraría algo de memoria y tener que lidiar con todos esos vacíos.

Te invito a revisar este artículos sobre las normalización de base de datos, especialmente las Reglas de Codd (Regla 3) que habla sobre los nulos.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos